# Issues with Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

Sorry back again, just a hopefully simple question.
Website Here: http://2sixd.co.nf/

Trying to make fancybox work in the gallery, which is does at a basic level (The fancybox website told me to come here for advice).

Basically I want to configure is so that is cycles through the pictures with arrows, with click to close, and no close button. Tried to use the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.fancybox-test').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',
            closeClick : true,
            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : true,
            nextClick : false,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });



    });
    </script>
```

Annoyingly, regardless of what I do, it functions with the default Fancybox settings, which is really annoyingly me, as I swear I have called everything correctly, including all the js files and classes on the images.

I have called all the pictures like this

```
<a class="fancybox-test" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="images/portfolio-01.png"><img src="images/portfolio-preview-01.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Despite this still no luck, and I've been trying for hours not, if anyone could shed some light I would be so grateful.

Small other issue, the first time you click on any of these pictures, a small black box appears in the center of the screen. Not sure if its a bug on my part, or the rubbish server I'm using, but does anyone else see this?

Thanks for any help!

James

Edit: Ok so I solved the black box issue, first one still remains however

Answer (score 0):

You're importing Fancybox twice -- two different versions

```
http://2sixd.co.nf/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
```

AND

```
http://2sixd.co.nf/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5
```

They're different versions.  The browser is picking up the first one, which is version 1.3.4.  The old API works in the console:

```
$('.fancybox-test').fancybox({
        'showCloseButton': false
    });
```

(see docs: http://fancybox.net/api)

That's why your configs aren't working.  You're using syntax for Fancybox 2

Comment: Ok I realized the older Fancybox was being used for a different feature on the website. So I removed all traces of the older version and upgraded all to Fancybox 2. The scrolling between the tabs on the website still works, which is what the older version of Fancybox was 
being used for, and it still works after the upgrade.
   However now, the Fancybox for the gallery doesn't even work, it just opens the pictures directly. Any chance you have any idea what is wrong, essentially all the code is unchanged, and I am using the correct config commands. What I really want if the Thumbnail helper.

Comment: Organize your files per http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/.  Right now you don't have any /fancybox/source/helpers/ directory.